# mouse with int 33h in ASM not working

Tags: assembly, mouse, nasm, dos, interrupt

I was playing around with assembly, compiling to .com files using NASM on Windows 7. For some reason, this doesn't work:

```
org 100h
run1:
mov ax, 3
int 33h
cmp bx, 0
je run1
xor bx, bx
run2:
mov ax, 3
int 33h
cmp bx, 0
je run2
int 20h
```

I think this should repeat `run1` until there is a mouse click, and then do the same with `run2`. Then, the program should quit. But, when I execute the program, it only waits for one mouse click.
What do I need to do to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this will do it (with comments).
(*code is untested*)

Basically, there are now 3 loops.
1.) Wait for the button to be pressed.
2.) Wait for the button to be released.
3.) Wait for the button to be pressed again.

```
org 100h
run1:
mov ax, 3
int 33h     #Check the mouse
cmp bx, 0   #See if button is pressed
je run1     #If Not pressed, go back and check again

xor bx, bx  #Okay, button is pressed, clear the result

run1a:
mov ax, 3
int 33h     #Check the mouse
cmp bx, 0   #See if button is released
jne run1a   #If NOT equal, then not released, go check again.

xor bx, bx  #button is released, clear the result

run2:
mov ax, 3
int 33h     #Check the mouse
cmp bx, 0   #if button is pressed (2nd time)
je run2     #If NOT pressed, go to top.

int 20h     #Button was pressed.  All done (we don't care when its released)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the mouse button stays pressed for some time. Hence after `run1` you need to wait till the button is release again, and then you can start checking for the second click again.

Comment: what's the best way to do that? I don't think that the int15h ah86h BIOS wait function works on windows 7.

Comment: For experimenting just do it the same way you wait for the pressed state.